# TypeLoadException: From C# code that attempts to interop with F# code

Tags: f#

I am struggling to resolve this runtime exception from my C# PCL that references an F# PCL:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100001d
>   (from typeref, class/assembly Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpResult`2,
>   FSharp.Core, Version=3.259.41.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a) occurred

NOTE:
I have ensured that my C# and F# project reference the same FSharp.Core version.

I remember having to add an XML file for versioning whenever I my test projects in F# wouldn't play nice with my F# projects. Is this the same case?

I added the following to my app config on my Xamarin.Forms PCL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.999.999.999" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

But I still receive the same error.

Answer (score 0):

FSharpResult is (I assume) the `Result<'TSuccess, 'TError>` type that was introduced in FSharp 4.1 so you should get FSharp.Core Version 4.4.1.0.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have all of my projects pointing to the latest version of FSharp.Core. However, I still run into the same issue.

Comment: Hmm... weird... Which is what version? Above, in the question you certainly show F# 4.0, something in one of the libraries referring to a type that doesn't exist yet, also says `FSharp.Core, Version=3.259.41.0`. Have you tried nugetting Fsharp.Core? It's possible that it's due to some PCL mixup. Any chance of putting this on GitHub for better debugging?

Comment: @ScottNimrod - If you're targeting F# 4.1, then the line `newVersion="4.4.0.0"` in your `app.config` should be `newVersion="4.4.1.0"`: see https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html#fsharpcore-version-numbers